# Getting ServiceStack RedisStackOverflow example to work

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis, servicestack

Hi I am new to ServiceStack+Redis. Now I am looking at RedisStackOverflow example that comes with ServiceStack.

I get an error when I try to run it:

> SocketException - An operation was attempted on something that is not
>   a socket.

`Call stack location: ServiceStack.Redis.PooledRedisclientManager.Finalize() Line 324`

The web page shows up but with no data. I also have Redis as Windows Services 2.4.6 32bit installed and verified it is working with the Redis Client.

I am running on a vista 32bit box, iis7 vs2010:
[image]

Sorry about the picture size, please zoom in to see the exception details.

Comment: Just tried it, RedisStackOverflow works on my machine :). It looks like it can't connect, make sure you don't have any firewalls blocking `localhost:6379`. Note: once you get running you should go to `/reset` to populate the page with test data.

Comment: From this link: http://www.servicestack.net/docs/redis-client/redis-client I got the cygwin redis v2.02 working. Couldn't get the others 2.2 and 2.4 to work. +1 for the /reset :D

Comment: I got redis 2.4 up and running now. Delete all the dlls that comes with the example. Nuget everything again. Thanks!

Comment: Cool you can add your comment as an answer so you can close the question.